# looping function for sloop but encounter error

Tags: excel, vba

I was working on a looping function that calculates slope. For the data loop, the code works but for the file loop, it says

> error 1004 : “Application-defined or Object-defined error”

I couldn't solve why was it the case and needed some help.

```
Sub B3_Sensitivity2()

Dim Xcol As Integer, Ycol As Integer
Dim n As Integer, m As Integer
m = 0

For file = 1 To 2
n = 0

    For data = 1 To 12

    Dim Yrng As Range, Xrng As Range, Grad As Range
    Set Yrng = Sheets("data").Range("F2:F8").Offset(n, m)
    Set Xrng = Sheets("data").Range("E2:E8").Offset(n, m)
    Set Grad = Sheets("data").Range("G2").Offset(n, m)

    Grad.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Slope(Yrng, Xrng) [**error 1004 occur here**]

    n = n + 7

    Next data

m = m + 10

Next file

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the values of n and m when it fails ?  If you use those same ranges can you enter working SLOPE() formula on the worksheet?

Comment: Can confirm this is your issue above ^ the code works fine up until the modified range includes a value that the `Slope` function does not expect. For instance, a completely blank range will give you an error or a range with text instead of numbers

Comment: Add `Debug.Print "Checking Yrng = " & Yrng.address, "Xrng=" & Xrng.address` just before the line where it fails

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check every iteration of your loop as you have a invalid value *(or values)* being fed into your equation somewhere. This will error out when your range variables include either of the below. Note that just one instance in either range will produce error 1004

1. Empty cells
2. Non-numeric cells

---

You can either `debug.print` your `file` & `data` as you loop to find the last successful range or step through your code. The goal for you is to find out what range is failing and then inspect each cell in that range. You will likely find a blank cell or a text cell which is causing your macro to fail.

—-

You should add some error handling here if you sometimes expect invalid cell values to be present and you want code to continue running

Answer (score 0):

Try to print Yrng and Xrng before Grad.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Slope(Yrng, Xrng), as they must be array numbers with the same length.